# How to save page state in Community Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, community

How to save page state in Community Builder?
I need to navigate from Page A(Component A) to Page B(Component B) (and vice versa) and save page field values.
Or better solution will be navigate between two components on one community page?